# With respect to the inversion of control pattern, is it strictly better to not have constructor calls outside of the composition root?

Tags: constructor, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, service-locator

I realize the question may be confusing and the word "better" may be problematic, but I could not think of a, well, better way to ask.

Let's say you are writing an application that has a single entry point, like `Main`, which also serves as the composition root for IoC:

- *From outside*, run application

  - `Main` or equivalent

    - `var container = new AwesomeContainer();`
    - `container.Install(new CompositionRootInstaller(startArgs));`

      - `container.Register( ... );`
      - `ApplicationMiddleware = container.Resolve<IMiddleware>();`
    - `ApplicationMiddleware.SignalStart();`

Here, `ApplicationMiddleware` might be a `ControllerFactory` in a web application, for instance.

Now, of course we will have lots of other services located by the `container` at the appropriate time (per request, for instance).

Sometimes we will run into situations where we don't feel like it's so bad to just assign, say, a default value to a field. But, in my view, this breaks IoC a little bit.

So, is it a true statement that (regardless of the marginal value of doing so) it is always better to avoid calling constructors or factories that call constructors or otherwise get components without calling the `container` once we leave the entry point?

#### Example: WinForms program

Here is the setup. It is a contrived example but I'm trying to focus on the issue at hand...

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var root = new AppCompositionRoot())
        {

        }
    }
}

class AppCompositionRoot : IDisposable
{
    private IWindsorContainer _container;

    public AppCompositionRoot(IWindsorContainer container = null)
    {
        _container = container ?? new WindsorContainer();
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        var formFactory = _container.Resolve<DefaultFormFactory>();

        Application.Idle += delegate
        {
            formFactory.ApplicationIsIdle();
        };

        Application.Run();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _container?.Dispose();
    }
}

public interface IFormFactory
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Form Create();
}

public class DefaultFormFactory : IFormFactory
{
    private readonly IWindsorContainer _container;

    private Form _lastForm;

    public DefaultFormFactory(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public Form Create()
    {
        return _container.Resolve<AppForm>();
    }

    public void ApplicationIsIdle()
    {
        _lastForm = _lastForm ?? Create();
        _lastForm.Show();
    }
}

public class AppForm : Form
{
    private readonly string _big;               // sensible default is "Welcome!"
    private readonly string _little;            // sensible default is a string varying by form, time of day, factory
    private readonly IList<object> _watched;    // sensible default is list empty.

    public AppForm(string bigMessage, string littleMessage, IList<object> watched)
    {
        _big = bigMessage;
        _little = littleMessage;
        _watched = watched;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        // do something with bigMesaage, littleMessage, etc.
    }
}
```

So let's start with concrete `AppForm`. It needs two `string`s and a `List<object>`.

Let's say for all of them there is a natural default that makes sense like 95% of the time, as in something that would be a `const string` on the `class`.

Regardless my question is - to really do IoC in the ideal sense, wouldn't it be true that you should always see constructors like these (clean constructors) and any defaults should be injected as well?

Comment: I am trying to understand your question. When you say "other services located by the container at the appropriate time", do you mean that they are located from outside the composition root? Can you explain what do you mean by assign a default value to a field? Is this a dependency field? Also, your final question, does it imply that it is OK to "get components" using the container after leaving the entry point?

Comment: You might want to add some concrete examples. I'm having an hard time understanding your question too.

Comment: @Steven and Yacoub, okay I can see that it is not the clearest question I've asked lol

Answer (score 3):

Inversion of Control simply states that *control* (whatever that is) is inverted. It doesn't mean that you have to invert *everything*; you should **invert that which you want to vary.**

If you're writing a *Hello world* application, and you don't want to vary anything, you can create the `string` within the implementation:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
```

On the other hand, if you want to be able to vary the message, you can pass it in as a [Primitive Dependency](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/07/02/PrimitiveDependencies):

```
public class Helo
{
    private readonly string message;

    public Helo(string message)
    {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void SayHello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.message);
    }
}
```

If it helps, Miško Hevery makes the distinction between [*newables* and *injectables*](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/09/30/to-new-or-not-to-new). On a different note, in [my book](http://amzn.to/12p90MG), I've attempted to make a distinction between *stable* and [*volatile* dependencies](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2006/08/24/718828.aspx).

You can `new` up values that you don't need to be able to control from the outside. If you need to control them from the outside (*Inversion of Control*, remember), then you need to inject them.

Comment: Mark, thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I think of IoC as not a hard rule but a conceptual technique for dealing with complexity in OOP. That said, I do think that we can say something like this: all things being equal (including programmer time), architecture A > architecture B with respect to IoC, if you catch my drift. So even if we do not use the "newables" maybe we will in the future and it will come in handy. For instance, I can follow a certain convention so that newable dependencies are also injectable via two ctors. The stable/volatile distinction is very helpful.

Comment: I can classify ctor parameters now by: injectable, newable, definitely stable, definitely voltaile. That means I can classify ctros themselves like: Ctor Type 1 (all strictly injectable parameters and stable), Type 2 (all strictly injectable parameters, some unstable), Type 3 (all injectable, some unstable, some optional) etc... and then a mirror set of groupings for ctors with those + newables (stable, not necessrily stable, volatile)... is this kind of where you are going?

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos It sounds like you're mentally setting up a matrix with *injectable/newable* on one axis, and *stable/volatile* on the other axis. I don't think that's a useful mental model. The point I attempted to get across is that you should inject those objects you need to *vary*, and new up the rest. These are the *injectables*, and they also tend to be the *volatile* dependencies. You could say that the *injectable/newable* concept describes the *what*, while the *stable/volatile* distinction describes the *why*.